# How to resolve all course dependencies in SQL?

Tags: sql, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

Stumbled upon this problem recently, and am struggling to do it in SQL. The table in question is in the form of course, then required course.

Example:
Course Requirement

```
MATH ENG  
ENG SCI  
ENG PHYSICS  
PHYSICS BIO
```

In a standard programming language, this can be done by some sort of search algorithm to get a list of dependencies (note that they can be nested as MATH DEPENDS ON ENG which depends on SCI), but I have no idea how one would do this with SQL. I tried using joins on equality, but the fact that they can be nested is throwing me off...

So if the query is MATH, then it should return
ENG, SCI, PHYSICS, BIO

Comment: Which database are you using?  Preferably one that supports recursive ctes...

Comment: It was categorized under SQL in general...so I'm not sure

Comment: If you know the maximum number of potential required courses, you could self join the table to itself that many times.  If not, then the answer is going to be database specific (dynamic sql, recursive cte, etc).

Comment: This can easily be solved using a recursive common table expression.

Comment: could you guys provide a link to a reference for this?

Comment: you could look at 'nested sets' if using `mysql`: http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/ . maybe interesting? : http://stefangabos.ro/php-libraries/zebra-mptt/